# C5 algorithm implementation?

Tags: classification, pattern-recognition

Do you know where can I find some information of this algorithm, to study it??. Is there already an example of its implementation, or, only [Quinlan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross_Quinlan) knows its implementation??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

His company, rulequest, has it: http://rulequest.com/GPL/C50.tgz

Comment: it is available under which license?

Comment: As the link says, it's gpl :)

Answer (score 2):

> C5.0 which Quinlan is commercially
>   selling is an improvement on C4.5.

According to this sentence from the wikipedia page this algorithm is not open for everyone. I guess it will take some effort to get something going by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The single threaded version is available under the GPL license. :)